# django admin change view not showing image thumbnail

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can list the image thumbnail in admin list view. I have done this in my model

```
def category_image(self):
    return '<img height=100px; width=100px; src="{}" />'.format(self.category_media.url)

category_image.short_description = 'Image'
category_image.allow_tags = True
```

But when i go to change view I dont get image. I just get url.
I want a thumbnail there too. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you show `list_display` of `ModelAdmin`, please?

Comment: list_display = ('category','category_image')

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace`'<img ...'` with `<img style="height=100px; width=100px;" src="{}" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line in your `admin.py`:

```
readonly_fields = ('category_image',)
```

---

BTW your HTML is wrong (`px` can only be used in CSS).

Fix:

```
def category_image(self):
    return '<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="%s">' % self.category_media.url
```